# Как сделать на сайте индексируемые табы с отдельным урл?

Tags: php, javascript, seo

Есть интернет-магазин, на карточке товара есть описание и др. в табах.

Как сделать, чтобы каждый таб при нажатии выдавал урл не как tovar#tab, а как tovar/#tab? То есть, каждый таб воспринимался и индексировался как отдельная страница и при переходе на страницу tovar/#tab открывалась страница товара с открытой вкладкой #tab.

Это реализовано на розетке и нескольких других интернет-магазинах.
И еще, кроме реализации, вопрос, как при этом избегается дублирование контента?

UPD. или там просто стоит переадресация через .htaccess адреса без слеша в конце на адрес со слешем?

Comment: про какую еще розетку речь?

Comment: не могли бы показать где именно на розетке это реализовано? вы про https://rozetka.com.ua/ ?

Comment: да, rozetka.ua. любой товар там имеет несколько табов. первоначальная ссылка карточки товара имеет вид https://hard.rozetka.com.ua/samsung_ls24d300hs/p1173155
а при нажатии на табы добавляется в конце /#tab-...
https://hard.rozetka.com.ua/samsung_ls24d300hs/p1173155/#tab=all
https://hard.rozetka.com.ua/samsung_ls24d300hs/p1173155/#tab=comments

Answer (score -2):

Посмотрите в сторону history.pushState js

Comment: Статья на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/

Comment: history.js меняет сам урл, но такой страницы не создает, т.е. если набрать в адресной строке потом полный урл со слешем и табом, то перейдет на общую страницу.

Comment: Делай вывод разных табов (tab1,tab1) на странице tovar исходя из GET (tovar/tab1, tovar/tab2)

Comment: 1) Делай вывод разных табов (tab1,tab2) на странице tovar при переходе по ссылкам с их указанием (tovar/tab1, tovar/tab2)

2) Сделай ссылки (<a href="tab1">) на табах вместо js переключателя

3) Затем при помощи preventDefault() замени стандартный переход по ссылке на переключение таба без перезагрузки

4) А с помощью history добавлением в урл название таба

зы и ссылки есть для seo (боты без js) и табы без перезагрузки для пользователя

Comment: спасибо, попробую